# APNS rejects notification with reason "DeviceTokenNotForTopic"

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-push-notifications, pushkit, usernotifications

I'm receiving this error only when trying to register for remote notifications using UserNotifications framework.
When using PushKit everything works ok.

```
    dispatch_queue_t mainQueue = dispatch_get_main_queue();
    // Create a push registry object
    self.voipRegistry = [[PKPushRegistry alloc] initWithQueue: mainQueue];
    // Set the registry's delegate to self
    self.voipRegistry.delegate = self;
    // Set the push type to VoIP
    self.voipRegistry.desiredPushTypes = [NSSet setWithObject:PKPushTypeVoIP];
```

Since Xcode 11 and iOS13 there are changes in PushKit to support CallKit, so I'm trying to use UserNotifications instead, as described in [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/pushkit/responding_to_voip_notifications_from_pushkit?language=objc)

```
Important
If you are unable to support CallKit in your app, you cannot use PushKit to handle push notifications. Instead, configure your app's push notification support with the UserNotifications framework.
```

I'm registering for remote notifications this way

```
- (BOOL) application:(UIApplication*) application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary*) launchOptions
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
```

And receiving token:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken
```

But when I'm sending notification from my server, I get DeviceTokenNotForTopic.
I'm not sure, if UserNotifications framework uses different APNs server or token format is different.

Answer (score 14):

APNS sends such error if bundleID of your app different from the `apns-topic` that you are sending from the server in request for voip push. 
Or a certificate for a voip push is generated for another bundleID.

Error code https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CommunicatingwithAPNs.html
More discussions here. https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-ios-sdk/issues/1020

Answer (score 4):

For me, I had changed the app's name and bundle ID and I hadn't renewed the device token and the certificate for notifications with images.

To solve that, I firstly went to the `Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles` section of my Apple Developer account and generated a new certificate with the `AppGroups` Capability.

Then I got a new device token in the calling of the `AppDelegate`'s function

`application( _ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data)`

After getting the token from the `deviceToken` parameter and using it for sending the notification, it started working again.

Answer (score -7):

if u r facing devicetokennotfortopic
then just try this

topic should be your bundle id of u r application
i fixed my issue

ex this is u r bundle id
com.app.xxx.SumNotService

i have removed SumNotService

com.app.xxx(this worked for me)

try